# Line number of python Disassembler(dis)

Tags: python, disassembly

I recently learn python.
I am wondering what is the line number for dis function.

```
import dis
def add(a,  b):
    a += 1 
    return a+b
dis.dis(add)
```

.

```
3         0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
          2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          4 INPLACE_ADD
          6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

4         8 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
         10 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
         12 BINARY_ADD
         14 RETURN_VALUE
```

There are 3 and 4.
Where is the line 1 and line 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

With `dis.dis(add)` you disassembly only your function add. So there a only two lines. The function add have only two lines too.

Comment: This does not answer the question...

Comment: I think it tries to say exactly the same thing as your own answer. Agree, this could be clearer; but I don't think it's _that_ unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The dis module prints the line numbers correctly. Line 1 is `import dis`, Line 2 is `def add(a, b):`.
You asked for the disassembly of the function only, hence, you only see lines 3 and 4.

```
$ cat -n test.py 
     1  import dis
     2  def add(a,  b):
     3      a += 1 
     4      return a+b
     5  print(dis.dis(add))
```